# How do I create a site where a registered user has a personal url for the site

Tags: django, wordpress

I'm working on a project and I want to make it in such a way that each registered user has a personal url for the site. For example, a user named james, when logged in, the url will look like this: `james.google.com`. Just like the same format as wordpress

P.S I'm using django

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is [Django Subdomains](https://django-subdomains.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). Have you looked into that package?

Comment: No I hadn't. Thanks a lot.